# string.gsub isn't finding my pattern

Tags: lua, gsub

A very generic title I know, my problem is that I am coding in lua and I'm trying to do a string.gsub but it just seems to not be finding my pattern. Below find all the details. Any help is appreciated.

**Msg Variable contains:**

```
{
    "started_at":1456170948017,
    "response":{
        "status":0,
        "size":"0",
        "headers":{
            "connection":"keep-alive"
        }
    },
    "authenticated_entity":{
        "consumer_id":"4be1d8e5-0270-489d-9538-42f05e00e2e6",
        "id":"39f1dbae-45ba-419a-abaa-d0750b5a2f4c"
    },
    "request":{
        "method":"POST",
        "uri":"\/SecureApi\/Logon",
        "size":"565",
        "request_uri":"http:\/\/192.168.10.122:8000\/SecureApi\/Logon",
        "querystring":{

        },
        "headers":{
            "x-consumer-id":"4be1d8e5-0270-489d-9538-42f05e00e2e6",
            "accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.8",
            "content-type":"application\/json",
            "connection":"keep-alive",
            "content-length":"78",
            "x-consumer-username":"kylec",
            "cache-control":"no-cache",
            "host":"192.168.10.122:8000",
            "cookie":"ASP.NET_SessionId=gwbujeb4k43c0gsscgmwaynh",
            "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
            "origin":"chrome-extension:\/\/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop",
            "accept":"*\/*",
            "apikey":"test",
            "postman-token":"524e7363-a5fc-a2d4-53f4-97a425f5ae30",
            "user-agent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/48.0.2564.116 Safari\/537.36"
        }
    },
    "client_ip":"192.168.10.143",
    "api":{
        "upstream_url":"https:\/\/stage.site.com",
        "request_path":"\/SecureApi",
        "id":"90ba1710-1e50-4070-95d0-deb76d33e312",
        "created_at":1454625397000,
        "name":"secure_account_stage",
        "request_host":"stage.site.com"
    },
    "latencies":{
        "request":0,
        "kong":0,
        "proxy":-1
    }
}
```

**Code:**

```
string.gsub(msg, '"querystring":{}', '"querystring":{'..BuildURLParameters()..'}')
string.gsub(msg, '},"headers":{','},"body":{'..BuildBodyParameters()..'},"headers":{')
```

**Expected Result:**

```
{
    "started_at":1456170948017,
    "response":{
        "status":0,
        "size":"0",
        "headers":{
            "connection":"keep-alive"
        }
    },
    "authenticated_entity":{
        "consumer_id":"4be1d8e5-0270-489d-9538-42f05e00e2e6",
        "id":"39f1dbae-45ba-419a-abaa-d0750b5a2f4c"
    },
    "request":{
        "method":"POST",
        "uri":"\/SecureApi\/Logon",
        "size":"565",
        "request_uri":"http:\/\/192.168.10.122:8000\/SecureApi\/Logon",
        "querystring":{ somejsoninhere },
        "body":{ somejsoninhere },
        "headers":{
            "x-consumer-id":"4be1d8e5-0270-489d-9538-42f05e00e2e6",
            "accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.8",
            "content-type":"application\/json",
            "connection":"keep-alive",
            "content-length":"78",
            "x-consumer-username":"kylec",
            "cache-control":"no-cache",
            "host":"192.168.10.122:8000",
            "cookie":"ASP.NET_SessionId=gwbujeb4k43c0gsscgmwaynh",
            "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
            "origin":"chrome-extension:\/\/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop",
            "accept":"*\/*",
            "apikey":"test",
            "postman-token":"524e7363-a5fc-a2d4-53f4-97a425f5ae30",
            "user-agent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/48.0.2564.116 Safari\/537.36"
        }
    },
    "client_ip":"192.168.10.143",
    "api":{
        "upstream_url":"https:\/\/stage.site.com",
        "request_path":"\/SecureApi",
        "id":"90ba1710-1e50-4070-95d0-deb76d33e312",
        "created_at":1454625397000,
        "name":"secure_account_stage",
        "request_host":"stage.site.com"
    },
    "latencies":{
        "request":0,
        "kong":0,
        "proxy":-1
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
{
    "started_at":1456170948017,
    "response":{
        "status":0,
        "size":"0",
        "headers":{
            "connection":"keep-alive"
        }
    },
    "authenticated_entity":{
        "consumer_id":"4be1d8e5-0270-489d-9538-42f05e00e2e6",
        "id":"39f1dbae-45ba-419a-abaa-d0750b5a2f4c"
    },
    "request":{
        "method":"POST",
        "uri":"\/SecureApi\/Logon",
        "size":"565",
        "request_uri":"http:\/\/192.168.10.122:8000\/SecureApi\/Logon",
        "querystring":{

        },
        "headers":{
            "x-consumer-id":"4be1d8e5-0270-489d-9538-42f05e00e2e6",
            "accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.8",
            "content-type":"application\/json",
            "connection":"keep-alive",
            "content-length":"78",
            "x-consumer-username":"kylec",
            "cache-control":"no-cache",
            "host":"192.168.10.122:8000",
            "cookie":"ASP.NET_SessionId=gwbujeb4k43c0gsscgmwaynh",
            "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
            "origin":"chrome-extension:\/\/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop",
            "accept":"*\/*",
            "apikey":"test",
            "postman-token":"524e7363-a5fc-a2d4-53f4-97a425f5ae30",
            "user-agent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/48.0.2564.116 Safari\/537.36"
        }
    },
    "client_ip":"192.168.10.143",
    "api":{
        "upstream_url":"https:\/\/stage.site.com",
        "request_path":"\/SecureApi",
        "id":"90ba1710-1e50-4070-95d0-deb76d33e312",
        "created_at":1454625397000,
        "name":"secure_account_stage",
        "request_host":"stage.site.com"
    },
    "latencies":{
        "request":0,
        "kong":0,
        "proxy":-1
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all: It would be better to just JSON decode it, add the data and JSON encode it again. Second of all: string.gsub does not ignore whitespace (like newlines) as you seem to think. e.g. ```'"querystring":{}'``` should be ```'"querystring":{%s*}'``` to make it also count newlines.

Comment: @EinsteinK ok, I'm getting it. Although I'd have to look at how the data is structured (table, etc) if it isn't in JSON. Naively this data is coming from nginx.

Answer (score 0):

As **@EinsteinK** pointed out, you are querying a string literal, that won't take whitespace into account.

The simplest way to get it working is exactly what he suggested: use `[["querystring":{%s*}]]`.

To leave out redundantly writing "querystring", you can write:

`string.gsub(msg, '("querystring"):{%s*}', '%1:{'..BuildURLParameters()..'}')`

The parentheses put whatever matched that part of the expression into a `capture` and `%n` inserts the n-th of the captures.

You could use captures to indent it, but if pretty output is not a concern, you shouldn't bother with that.

[Repl.it sample](https://repl.it/BqBJ)

**Output:**

```
{
    "started_at":1456170948017,
    "response":{
        "status":0,
        "size":"0",
        "headers":{
            "connection":"keep-alive"
        }
    },
    "authenticated_entity":{
        "consumer_id":"4be1d8e5-0270-489d-9538-42f05e00e2e6",
        "id":"39f1dbae-45ba-419a-abaa-d0750b5a2f4c"
    },
    "request":{
        "method":"POST",
        "uri":"\/SecureApi\/Logon",
        "size":"565",
        "request_uri":"http:\/\/192.168.10.122:8000\/SecureApi\/Logon",
        "querystring":{somejson},
        "headers":{
            "x-consumer-id":"4be1d8e5-0270-489d-9538-42f05e00e2e6",
            "accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.8",
            "content-type":"application\/json",
            "connection":"keep-alive",
            "content-length":"78",
            "x-consumer-username":"kylec",
            "cache-control":"no-cache",
            "host":"192.168.10.122:8000",
            "cookie":"ASP.NET_SessionId=gwbujeb4k43c0gsscgmwaynh",
            "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
            "origin":"chrome-extension:\/\/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop",
            "accept":"*\/*",
            "apikey":"test",
            "postman-token":"524e7363-a5fc-a2d4-53f4-97a425f5ae30",
            "user-agent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/48.0.2564.116 Safari\/537.36"
        }
    },
    "client_ip":"192.168.10.143",
    "api":{
        "upstream_url":"https:\/\/stage.site.com",
        "request_path":"\/SecureApi",
        "id":"90ba1710-1e50-4070-95d0-deb76d33e312",
        "created_at":1454625397000,
        "name":"secure_account_stage",
        "request_host":"stage.site.com"
    },
    "latencies":{
        "request":0,
        "kong":0,
        "proxy":-1
    }
}   1
```